# Windows Phone 8.0 background agent is it posible to wire up with system trigger for recieved Sms?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Hi everyone i tried to wire my background  task with  System trigger events (for sms) but i just cant do it maybe i am still noob programmer but is it even  posible to wire systemtrigger for incoming sms with bacground agent for windows phone 8 ?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/windows.applicationmodel.background.systemtrigger.triggertype.ASPx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/windows.applicationmodel.background.systemtrigger.triggertype.ASPx

```
protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
{
    string toastMessage = "";

    if (task is PeriodicTask)
    {   
        toastMessage = "Periodic task running.";
    }
    else
    {
        toastMessage = "Resource-intensive task running.";
    } 

    ShellToast toast = new ShellToast();
    toast.Title = "Background Agent Sample";
    toast.Content = toastMessage;
    toast.Show();

    NotifyComplete();
}
```

Comment: Show what did you tried so far, so someone can help you.

Comment: I made agent which runs at background on periodic and response intensitive tasks

Comment: Great, but you forgot to show it :) Others can hardly help you with something only you can see.

Comment: Nooo, this won't work definitely. It should be part of your question and also format it, please. But you should read at least the [StackOverflow's help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first. You could avoid these useless comments.

Comment: I am sory i am new to this site i hope i gave enough info now ;)

Comment: Yeah, I know, I was reviewing your first post :) But please, read that help first and also help on post formatting (Markdown). Code you posted is completely broken. Trust me, it's not bullying, I'm trying to help you. You have little chance for an answer to a poor question. Questions are usually answered in a matter of minutes (depending on a question of course), but your question is here for 4 days already and without any answer.